# Using a DLL exported from D

Tags: python, dll, d

I've created a simple encryption program in D, and I had the idea to make a DLL from it and try to import it to, for example, Python.

I've could simply call my `main` function, becouse it dosn't need any params. But when I get to my encrytion method, **it uses dynamic-lenght `ubyte[]` arrays**, but as far as I know, they **don't exist in other C/C++ based langs**.

For example, there's the first line of one of my funcs:
`ubyte[] encode(ubyte[] data, ubyte[] key){`

But I can't use an array without fixed lenght in other languages!
How can I import that function, for example, in Python?

**EDIT:**

I know that I can create a wrapper that takes a pointer and the lenght of the array, but isn't there a more elegant solution?
(Where I don't need to use D to use a lib written in D)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you'd do it in Python, but a C wrapper would be done by making a little function that takes a data pointer and a length, then forwards that to the slice. So if you can figure out how to do a Python array to a C array, then you do C to D and you're set.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Yeah, that was my first idea. Looks like good, but I think there's a more elegant soulution.

Comment: Maybe this is of help: https://wiki.dlang.org/Win32_DLLs_in_D

Comment: https://dlang.org/spec/interfaceToC.html Seems there is no matching type in `C` for any `type[]`...

Comment: Maybe you can do that already with pyd ( https://github.com/ariovistus/pyd ) ??

Comment: Pyd looks nice... I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well tbh. there's no real elegant way other than wrapping a pointer with a length or wrapping to C arrays and then to D.

However you can make a somewhat elegant purpose with the first way using a struct that has a pointer, a length and a property that converts it to a D array.

Then the function you export takes your struct, all that function should do is call an internal function that takes an actual D array and you'd simply pass the array to it and the conversion would happen at that moment through alias this and the conversion property.

An example usage is here:
    module main;

```
import core.stdc.stdlib : malloc;

import std.stdio;

struct DArray(T) {
    T* data;
    size_t length;
    /// This field can be removed, only used for testing purpose
    size_t offset;

    @property T[] array() {
        T[] arr;

        foreach(i; 0 .. length) {
            arr ~= data[i];
        }

        return arr;
    }

    alias array this;

    /// This function can be removed, only used for testing purpose
    void init(size_t size) {
        data = cast(T*)malloc(size * T.sizeof);
        length = size;
    }

    /// This function can be removed, only used for testing purpose
    void append(T value) {
        data[offset] = value;

        offset++;
    }
}

// This function is the one exported
void externalFoo(DArray!int intArray) {
    writeln("Calling extern foo");

    internalFoo(intArray);
}

// This function is the one you use
private void internalFoo(int[] intArray) {
    writeln("Calling internal foo");

    writeln(intArray);
}


void main() {
    // Constructing our test array
    DArray!int arrayTest;
    arrayTest.init(10);

    foreach (int i; 0 .. 10) {
        arrayTest.append(i);
    }

    // Testing the exported function 
    externalFoo(arrayTest);
}
```

Here is an absolute minimum version of how to do it

```
struct DArray(T) {
    T* data;
    size_t length;

    @property T[] array() {
        T[] arr;

        foreach(i; 0 .. length) {
            arr ~= data[i];
        }

        return arr;
    }

    alias array this;

}

// This function is the one exported
void externalFoo(DArray!int intArray) {
    writeln("Calling extern foo");

    internalFoo(intArray);
}

// This function is the one you use
private void internalFoo(int[] intArray) {
    writeln("Calling internal foo");

    writeln(intArray);
}
```

Comment: Looks like good, but eh, it's simpler to use C-wrappers for pointers and lengths.